# C# how to avoid multiple switches (delegate?)

Tags: c#, delegates, switch-statement

I am using multiple switches in my code to reflect species choice in listbox. One of them looks like:

```
    private int getOrganelleLength() {
        int species = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        switch (species) {
            case 0:
                //Console.WriteLine("arabidopsis");
                return 154478;

            case 1:
                //Console.WriteLine("oryza");
                return 134525;

            case 2:
                //Console.WriteLine("glycine");
                return 152218;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                throw new Exception("wrong speices choice");
        }
    }
```

second looks like:

```
    private int getLengthOfChromosome(int number) {

        int species = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        switch (species) {
            case 0:
                //Console.WriteLine("arabidopsis");
                return arabidopsis_chromosomes[number - 1];

            case 1:
                //Console.WriteLine("oryza");
                return oryza_chromosomes[number - 1];

            case 2:
                //Console.WriteLine("glycine");
                return glycine_chromosomes[number - 1];

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                throw new Exception("wrong speices choice");
        }
```

I somehow feel that this is not the clearest solution, this multiple use of switch. However, both functions return completely different values (based on species choice, of course). I would love to learn how to improve my code, if there is a way to. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use a different class for each specie.

Comment: Thanks @devouredelysium , this is good idea to do. I will put all information about species into separate classes. But then I still will want to get data based on species chosen.. Would be nice if it would be possible to write code with same unknown_specie and then initialize it with real specie chosen..

Answer (score 1):

I assume `arabidopsis_chromosomes` et al, are arrays or lists.

Just add them to an array or list.

Eg (extremely simplified):

```
object[][] foo = {{ 1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};

object Get(int x, int y)
{
  return foo[x][y];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would definitely shorten the code, thanks:) But I am not sure if it would be more readible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on refacotring methods. This sounds like [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

So use classes for your data objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
private int getOrganelleLength() {
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>() { {0, 154478}, {1, 134525}, {2, 152218} };
    return dict[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}

private int getLengthOfChromosome(int number) {
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, Func<int>>() {
           {0, () => arabidopsis_chromosomes[number - 1]},
           {1, () => oryza_chromosomes[number - 1]}
           {2, () => glycine_chromosomes[number - 1]}}; 
    return dict[listBox1.SelectedIndex]();
 }
```

In the last case you don't need actually Func, as you can just add to dictionary values arabidopsis_chromosomes, wrote that more for an example.

Anyway that will work only if you have very very simple switch. **If you need some more difficult stuff to write, do not use that.** For that case you should refactor your code and use polymorphism and factories.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should throw a `NotImplementedException` in your `default` case and not an `Exception`.

Then, you should take a look at [`Func<T, TResult>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

You could have your code looking something like

```
private int GetInformationAboutSpecies(ListBox listBox, ISwitchCaseResolver helper)
{
    return helper.GetInformation(listBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```

You can then implement a concrete class of `ISwitchCaseResolver` interface for each of your species. You may also consider using a [Factory pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) to call the correct implemtantion of your interface.